# symfony 1.4 functional test report

Tags: symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I write a functional test for my symfony software and run it from command prompt. Now I want to get the result of functional test as a report(in a text file or word file etc).

How can U resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using :

```
$ php symfony test:functional --xml=log.xml
```

You can retrieve a xml.

> If you want to integrate your test suite in a continuous integration
>   process, use the `--xml` option to force the `test:functional` task to generate a
>   JUnit compatible XML output.